# How to fetch the file name and file size from Google drive and show that inside Download button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

As you can see there is a place for the file size and file name inside the download button, i want to fetch the Google drive file name and file size and show the values inside this download button. Is that possible?

```css
.download-button {
   background-color:#00FF55;
   height:90px;
   width:300px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;
   }

.button-wrapper {
   padding-top:19px;
   display:block;
}

.button-title {
   font-weight:bold;
   display:block;
   text-align:center;
   color:#343434;
   font-size:26px;
   height:auto;
   }

#info-wrapper {
display:block;
text-align:center;
margin-left:10px;
font-size:14px;
color:#777;
}


.file-size {
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:left;
   
   }

.file-name {
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:right;
   }

.file-name:before {
   content:"-";
   margin-right:3px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="download-button">
   <div class="button-wrapper">
    <span class="button-title">Download</span>

    <div id="info-wrapper">

     <span class="file-size">
     <!-- the code to fetch the google drive file size -->
     4.3 Mb
     </span>
    <span class="file-name">
    <!-- the code to fetch the google drive file name -->
    filename.zip
    </span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files

In the google drive REST api:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get

This will return your metadata object and you can parse the json for the info you want.

Comment: @drelliot is there any step by step tutorial to do that? actually i am new to this google drive api thingy

Comment: Have you used a REST API before?

You'll need to use some javascript to call the GET url and then process the data.

You can use XMLHttpRequests
http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-javascript.html

or something like JQuery.get()

Once you have the data, parse it as a json object.